# How to create bean via method marked by @Bean, and use properties from yaml file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

There is a spring-boot project use yaml as config file.

**application.yaml - partly:**

```
spring:
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
```

**DummyConfig.java:**

```
@Configuration
public class DummyConfig {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DummyConfig.class);

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String host;
    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private int port;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
    logger.info("redis host: {}", host);
    }

    @Bean
    public String mappingMongoConverter() {
    logger.info("redis host: {}", host);
    return "HelloBean";
    }
}
```

The logger line in `init()` is printed,
while the logger line in `mappingMongoConverter()` is **not** printed,

**The questions are:**

- Why is that happen?
- Inside a method annotated by `@Bean`, how to use a property from yaml?

---

### **@Update**

After discussion & testing, the question has become about name of methods marked by `@Bean`, but not about properties from yaml or other config files.

Comment: where is mappingMongoConverter function? you can use properties inside methods with `@Bean`.

Comment: @pvpkiran Renamed as `hello()` it's just any method marked by @Bean.

Comment: it works fine for me. log inside hello is printed with host

Comment: @pvpkiran I am using spring-boot 1.5.8, which version do you use ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Are you sure your method name is called `hello` or for simplicity you have changed the name.. With method name hello it works perfectly fine. Test it again?

Comment: Your initial question is valid... if you name your function as `mappingMongoConverter` then it won't be called

Comment: @pvpkiran You are right, the method name matters, when use `mappingMongoConverter` as method name, it use the method name as bean name, which conflict with another bean, so it failed. When use `mappingMongoConverter2` it succeed, thanks.

Comment: @pvpkiran I changed the method name in question back. Anyhow, the discussion have kind figured out why it won't work.

Comment: yes  you are right. about the conflict. cheers

Comment: @pvpkiran I did more test, and posted an answer, seems those names are kind of reversed.

Answer (score 0):

I added following methods into spring-boot application's entry class `Application.java`:

```
/**
 * Create a command line runner, that print bean names.
 * 
 * @param ctx
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner initRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
    return args -> {
        printBeanNames((ConfigurableApplicationContext) ctx);
    };
}

/**
 * Print bean names.
 * 
 * @param ctx
 */
private void printBeanNames(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames); // sort,

    logger.info("bean count: {}", beanNames.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < beanNames.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("\t[%4d]: %s\n", i, beanNames[i]);
    }
}
```

which would print names of all beans in application context, in alphabetical order.

And **no** dependency about `mongodb` is added in the application.

**The testing result is:**

- First, the `@Bean` method is named `helloBean`, then it could be created successfully, both logger lines are printed.
- If rename the `@Bean` method to any previous printed bean names (e.g `requestContextFilter`), then the logger line in the `@Bean` method will not be printed, which means the method failed to create the bean, I guess.
  But the built-in bean `requestContextFilter` is still created since it's in the list of printed bean names.
- If rename the `@Bean` method to `mappingMongoConverter` (*which is not in previous printed bean names, but a bean of that name will be created if you have `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` in dependency*). The result is: the bean also won't be created, same case as `requestContextFilter`.

**My guess:**

- Maybe those special names (e.g `requestContextFilter`, `mappingMongoConverter`) are defined somewhere in `spring-boot-starter-web` (*or another basic spring-boot dependency*), and if a user-defined `@Bean` method use the same name, then it will just fail to create the bean silently, without even a warning.